# Removing ridge by smoothing

Tags: mesh

How can I remove the ridge created by the edge of the T-shirt?

I'm using the mesh in an acoustic simulator, and a distinct ridge is sure to create some unnecessary echo artefacts.

Is there any better alternative than simply decimating the mesh?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Modifiers:

You could try the [*Smooth* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Smooth::).

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Smooth::):

> This modifier smooths a mesh by flattening the angles between adjacent faces in it, just like Smooth in the Editing context. It smooths without subdividing the mesh – the number of vertices remains the same.

## Sculpting:

Another option is to try and remove it manually with [*Sculpting*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Sculpt_Mode).

1. Enter sculpt mode (in *3D view > Header*) with your object selected:

   [image]
2. Pick the *Smooth* brush (<kbd>S</kbd>) or *Tool shelf > Brush*:

   [image]
3. Sculpt over the ridge with <kbd>LMB</kbd>:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'd try `Sculpt mode`, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag mouse while holding left mouse button over the ridge to smooth it out.